# Issue With Content Script in Simple Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm really new to programming and had a quick question.

I am writing a simple Chrome extension that logs all of a users scrolling and adds up the distance scrolled in pixels. I want to track it for every website, save it to chrome.storage.local and then in my browser_action js I want to retrieve that number and display it.

The issue is that the content script does not seem to be running. I added a console.log to log whenever a scroll event happens and that is not occurring. Here are my files:

**ScrollerJS (This is my conent script)**

```
var totalScroll;
var lastKnownScrollPos = 0;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        console.log(lastKnownScrollPos);
        totalScroll += Math.abs(window.scrollY - lastKnownScrollPos);
        lastKnownScrollPos = window.scrollY;
        chrome.storage.local.set({scroll: totalScroll});
    });
});
```

**Popup.JS**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  chrome.storage.local.get("count", function(data) {
  console.log(data)
  document.getElementById("#miles-scrolled").textContent = data.count;
});
})
```

**Popup.HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Scroller</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
        height:300px;
        width: 300px;
      }
      #status {
        /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
        white-space: pre;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width: 300px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="status">You've scrolled this many miles:</div>
    <div id="miles-scrolled"</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version":2,

"name":"Scroll by the Mile",
"description":"Measures distance scrolled in miles",
"version":"1.0",

"content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["scroller.js"]
    }
    ],

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon":"icon.png",
    "default_title":"Scroll by the Mile",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
},

"permissions":[
  "activeTab",
  "<all_urls>",
  "storage"
]
}
```

I would appreciate any help on figuring out why this isn't working/if I'm way off base.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [run_at](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), by default this section is `document_idle`, which means the content script is injected after `window.onload` event fires, it means you can't catch `DOMContentLoaded` event then in fact you didn't bind your event listener.

To solve this, I'd like to provide two approaches

1. Add `"run_at": "document_start"` to your `manifest.json`, which means your script is injected before any other DOM is constructed.

   manifest.json

   ```
   {
       "manifest_version": 2,
       "name": "Scroll by the Mile",
       "description": "Measures distance scrolled in miles",
       "version": "1.0",
       "content_scripts": [
           {
               "matches": [
                   "<all_urls>"
               ],
               "js": [
                   "scroller.js"
               ],
               "run_at": "document_start"
           }
       ],
       "browser_action": {
           "default_icon":"icon.png",
           "default_title": "Scroll by the Mile",
           "default_popup": "popup.html"
       },
       "permissions": [
           "activeTab",
           "<all_urls>",
           "storage"
       ]
   }
   ```
2. Extract your from `DOMContentLoaded` event listener, because by default when your content script is injected, `DOMContentLoaded` event is ensured fired.

   scroller.js

   ```
   var totalScroll;
   var lastKnownScrollPos = 0;

   window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
       console.log(lastKnownScrollPos);
       totalScroll += Math.abs(window.scrollY - lastKnownScrollPos);
       lastKnownScrollPos = window.scrollY;
       chrome.storage.local.set({ scroll: totalScroll });
   });
   ```